# customize django runserver output

Tags: python, django, logging

I want edit out put of django runserver ... i want add now object address like `apps.views.index`

add all query in this request

how can change code for this setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think best way is use logging and add some code to this

like

```
from django.db import connection
sql=connection.queries
```

and

```
doc = {
                'record_hash': hash,
                'level': record.level,
                'channel': record.channel or u'',
                'location': u'%s:%d' % (record.filename, record.lineno),
                "message": record.msg,
                'module': record.module or u'<unknown>',
                'occurrence_count': 0,
                'solved': False,
                'app_id': app_id,
                'sql': sql,
            }
```

read more about this in http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/

Comment: and doc goes where exactly?

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't recommend modifying the runserver command, but...

[django-devserver](https://github.com/dcramer/django-devserver) has a replacement for the `manage.py runserver` command that allows extending the output to show any information you're interested in.

The instructions on the page linked above show how to install, and near the bottom there is a "Building Modules" that shows an example for extending the output.

I'm not exactly sure what you're looking to output, but maybe something like:

```
from devserver.modules import DevServerModule

class ViewNameModule(DevServerModule):
    logger_name = 'view name module'

    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        self.logger.info('View name: %s' % '.'.join([view_func.__module__, view_func.func_name]))
```

Comment: A [process_view middleware](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/http/middleware/#process-view) can do pretty much the same thing - the architecture here is based on middleware. Combine it with a [context processor](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext) if you want it available in every view, and then just spit it out as a template variable.

Answer (score 0):

Not the exactly the answer to your question, but I think [django-debug-toolbar](https://github.com/robhudson/django-debug-toolbar) shows all the queries and many other useful information.